# MS Word - How to export all ACCEPTED changes?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm looking for a way to extract all **accepted** changes from a Word doc. To be clear, I want to pull a list of all changes **that have already been accepted**. Said again, the document revisions are now completed, but I want to extract a list of all the changes that were made.

Context: I have a team of people revising a 100 page document. We want to keep a record of all the changes made to the document.

Comment: option 3 here? https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/3-effective-methods-extract-comments-word-document/

Comment: By "accepted changes", do you mean tracked changes accepted in Word or tracked changes approved by a human being?